Not able to mock mutation in Redux Toolkit Query
Below is the code I have for one of the query in Redux Toolkit Query
workflowQuery.ts
export const workflowQuery = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'workflowQuery',
  baseQuery: await fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4040',
    prepareHeaders,
  })
  },
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getworkflowById: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => {
        return {
          url: api/workflowByName,
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
        };
      },
    }),
  }),

I am trying to write test cases for above code -
workflowQuery.test.ts
const server = setupServer(
  http.post(`http://localhost:4040/api/workflowByName`, () => {
    return HttpResponse.json({
      fileObject: 'PD94bWwgdm',
    });
  }),
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

test('useMutation hook sets data to the *emphasized text*resolved response on success', async () => {
    const result = { fileObject: 'PD94bWwgdm' };

    function User() {
      const [getworkFlowById, { data }] =
        workflowQuery.endpoints.getworkflowById.useMutation();

      return (
        <div>
          <div data-testid="result">{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() =>
              getworkFlowById({ path: '/content/workflow/UDJSNkxtZzI=.bpmn' })
            }
          >
            GetWorkflowById
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    renderComponentWithProviders(<User />);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('GetWorkflowById'));
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.getByTestId('result').textContent).toBe(JSON.stringify(result)),
    );
  });

The only problem is while executing the test case and running the query getworkflowById, it is not picking the base query which has the URL - http://localhost:4040.
It means it runs the test case with this URL - api/workflowByName which is not a valid URL and hence test case is getting failed.
Please note that I have setup the server for http://localhost:4040/api/workflowByName so ideally while running the test case it should pick the base query and make the URL as http://localhost:4040/api/workflowByName instead of api/workflowByName.
Anybody has any idea on this. Please share your thoughts.
